# Change pattern with sed only for matching lines in a df file

Tags: sed

I have a data frame such as

```
A   B   C   D
Sp1 pattern1    unknown_species family_a
Sp2 pattern1    unknown_species family_a
Sp3 pattern3    unknown_species family_a
Sp4 pattern1    unknown_species family_a
Sp5 pattern5    unknown_species family_a
```

And I would like with a bash command to sed `'s@unknown_species@known_species@g'`
but only for lines with a `"pattern1"`

So I should get here in the exemple :

```
A   B   C   D
Sp1 pattern1    known_species   family_a
Sp2 pattern1    known_species   family_a
Sp3 pattern3    unknown_species family_a
Sp4 pattern1    known_species   family_a
Sp5 pattern5    unknown_species family_a
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following. Here search for string first in line if found then do subsitution on it(search_string/s/old/new method)

```
sed '/pattern1/s/unknown_species/known_species/'  Input_file
```